# What is a platform when we talk about embedded systems?

Tags: embedded, porting

I am trying to learn linux porting, booting and other things and one thing that specially comes is platform. What is it

```
a cpu
a board 
an overall term as board + cpu
```

like when we say platform specific code do we mean architecture(of cpu) specific code ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform

Comment: so in terms of embedded its just about hardware , like architecture as arm, dec, alpha etc

Comment: @mrigendra:  I am not sure how you drew that conclusion from the link Oli posted.  It quite clearly says in the first paragraph *"Typical platforms include a hardware architecture, **an operating system (OS) and runtime libraries**"*

Comment: i read this line "Platforms may also include:

Hardware alone, in the case of small embedded systems. Embedded systems can access hardware directly, without an OS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on context. If you are porting Linux, the platform from that point-of-view is the hardware you are porting it to.  If you are writing applications to run on Linux on that hardware, then the platform is *both) the OS and the hardware.

Furthermore if you were targeting a GUI framework such as KDE or Gnome, that that would be "part of the "platform" too; or if you were running Java code, the *platform* would include the JVM.

Essentially it is the stuff that is already there that the code needs to pre-exist in order to run the code. Generally a platform might consist of *layers*; the "platform" as such comprises of whatever layers exist below that which you might be developing at that time.

Comment: your first para of answer is what i was looking for.